# iterate over pdf files with pdfcrop in a makefile and assign dependency

Tags: makefile, latex, crop, gnu

I am able to iterate over pdf files (pictures) in my makefile to crop the margins. For this I am using the pdfcrop function of TexLive on Windows 10. But now I am not able to create a dependency. If a pdf file is not cropped or there is a new pdf file that is not cropped in my picture folder, pdfcrop shall crop the margins and save it with the same name in the same folder (so actually override the old pdf file). I think this might be easy, but I just can't figure out how to do this. This is my Code in the makefile.

```
MAIN_FILE = Dissertation
FIG_DIR  = ./Bilder/Abbildungen
FIG_FILES  := $(wildcard $(FIG_DIR)/*.pdf)

all: $(MAIN_FILE).pdf

$(MAIN_FILE).pdf: $(MAIN_FILE).tex $(CROP_FILES)
    pdflatex $(MAIN_FILE).tex

CROP_FILES = ${FIG_FILES:%=%.crop}

$(CROP_FILES): $(FIG_FILES) # this line doesn't seem work correctly
    $(foreach FIG_FILE, $(FIG_FILES), $(call CROP, $(FIG_FILE)))

define CROP
    pdfcrop $(1) $(1).crop

endef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution, which will (hopefully) check timestamp for each PDF file, and activate CROP only on updated/new files.

The cropped file is left in the same file name. If the timestamp of the '.crop' file is newer that the 'pdf' file, it means file is cropped, otherwise, PDF file will be cropped, and the '.crop' file will be touched.

```
MAIN_FILE = Dissertation
FIG_DIR  = ./Bilder/Abbildungen
FIG_FILES  := $(wildcard $(FIG_DIR)/*.pdf)

all: $(MAIN_FILE).pdf

    # The '.crop' timestamp capture the time the file was cropped
CROP_FILES=${FIG_FILES:%=%.crop}

%.crop: %
        pdfcrop $< $<
        touch $@

$(MAIN_FILE).pdf: $(MAIN_FILE).tex $(CROP_FILES)
        pdflatex $(MAIN_FILE).tex
```

**Modification to place 'crop' files to timestamp folder**

```
TS_DIR=ts
CROP_FILES = ${FIG_FILES:${FIG_DIR}/%=${TS_DIR}/%.crop}

${TS_DIR}/%.crop: ${FIG_DIR}/%
        @mkdir -p ${TS_DIR}
        pdfcrop $< $<
        touch $@
```

Suggesting more testing, as logic is more complex. The '%.crop' target is replaced with a rule to generate them at ${TS_DIR}

Comment: It is still not working, and I don't know why because you have surely tested your code and it worked fine. I am getting this error: PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `Bilder/Abbildungen/pic1-crop.pdf'.
touch Bilder/Abbildungen/pic1.pdf.crop
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, touch Bilder/Abbildungen/pic1.pdf.crop, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Bilder/Abbildungen/pic1.pdf.crop] Error 2

Comment: To clarify, I am running the make command in the command line of Windows 10 in the same folder as my latex project. Pdfcrop is from TexLive 2019. I tried a similar solution found on the internet 2 days ago without success too.

Comment: Can you double check the 'pdfcrop', it should have only one parameter, and should not reference the .crop file, just the .pdf file. I can not comment on Window10, I'm testing/running on Linux.

Comment: I double checked and pdfcrop always creates the file like "pic1-crop.pdf.crop. So the cropped file is not left in the same filename. I really don't know what to do at the moment. I already tried the makefile in the Powershell, but the problem remains.

Comment: Note that the '.crop' file is only used to track if the file was cropped. It doe not actually contain anything (ls should show a zero size file). The error message indicates you system does not have 'touch  Bilder/Abbildungen/pic1.pdf.crop". Do you have the touch utility in your path ?

Comment: alright, I installed GnuWin32 coreUtils and now I have the touch command :) Also I had to add a second "$<" behind "pdfcrop $<" to define the output name will have the same name as the input file. So the .crop files are created also too now. Is there a way to delete them or does it have to be like this because there are now a lot of "trash" files in it?

Comment: Happy to hear you are able to use proposed solution. Each crop file act as a flag to avoid reprocessing. The only downside for removing them is having to re-crop all files.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to make the .crop files invisible. This would be at least a good solution for me. Or create something like a timestamp folder where all the .crop files are. Later it could happen that I have the same situation with my R files, so I could move them all to this folder. Is this possible?

Comment: Should be easy to place all crop files into ‘ts’ folder. In the ritzy will require changing the CROP_FILES rule, and the %.crop rule - add ts/ prefix.

Comment: I tried your solution with changing the CROP_FILES rule and the %.crop rule. The problem is the path are always different then. I know what the idea is but it is not working correctly. I could also move the files after creation but I think it would be an unnecessary step.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: what do you mean 'path are always different'. Can you give an example so that I can understand ?

Comment: It is working like a charm now. Thank you very very much for all your effort!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you stored the cropped file in the same name as the original PDF file, Make will not be able to tell if a specific file is cropped. As an alternative, consider naming the cropped files differently (e.g., filename.pdf.crop)

```
    # Add '.crop' suffix to the original file name
CROP_FILES = ${FIG_FILES:%=%.crop}

    # Recreate ALL CROPPED files, on changes to ANY source file
$(CROP_FILES): $(FIG_FILES) # this line doesn't seem work correctly
    $(foreach FIG_FILE, $(FIG_FILES), $(call CROP, $(FIG_FILE)))

    # Based on doc, 2nd parameter to pdfcrop name the output file.
define CROP
    pdfcrop $(1) $(1).crop

endef
```

Note that this version will re-crop all PDF files when a single PDF files is added, recreated. If this is a time consuming operation, you can extend the Makefile to perform the check on each, and improve performance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. If I use this code it says make: Nothing to be done for `all'. I am new to this, but I think I have implemented it the right way and in my directory are not updated files with different time stamps. How is it possible to check on each pdf file? This would be actually much better because there might be like 60 to 70 files later.

Comment: How are the PDF files getting created ?

Comment: I am using Visio to export the pictures as pdf.

Comment: You can add 'check' target: 'check: ; echo $(CROP_FILES)', then run 'make check'. It will help you validate the value of CROP_FILES - should be list of PDF files, each with '.crop' suffix.

Comment: Also, to clarify, the answer code should be placed after the definition for MAIN_FILE in the question code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it is not working yet. I updated my code of this thread. I also don't understand your solution of checking the single files. I am new to this and trying my best ;)

Comment: @Bolle - can you post the output from 'make check' as per comment above. It will help debug the problem.

Comment: The output of echo looks like this: ./Bilder/Abbildungen/pic1.pdf.crop ./Bilder/Abbildungen/pic2.pdf.crop ./Bilder/Abbildungen/pic3.pdf.crop

Comment: @Bolle, I've posted a different solution in a different answer. It should perform the crop test per file, to improve performance.